# jQuery clean way to get href array and rebuild it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm still learning and although my method works, I'm not convinced it's elegant and could be improved. Basically we have a system where I CAN'T control the output so I'm using the following code to get the `href` of an anchor and manipulate it to point to the correct place.

**HTML**

```
<a class="shop-return" href="/_shop/category/prodect/">Link</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
//set url object
var link = $(".shop-return");
//get url objects href value + split it into parts
var linkUrl = link.attr("href").split("/");
    /*remove the starting blank space and the ending 
    product part of url*/
    linkUrl.splice(-2,2)
    linkUrl.shift();

//build new link
var newLinkUrl = linkUrl.join("/");
//set new link on object
link.attr('href', "/" + newLinkUrl + "/");
```

Any suggestions on how to make this cleaner / more efficient - and if I've gone about things in the right away or not would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative is to use regular expressions to shorten the code a little:

```
var link =  $(".shop-return");
var linkUrl = link.attr("href").match(/\/([_a-z]+)\/([a-z]+)\//);

link.attr('href', linkUrl[0]);
```

This uses regEx matches. `linkUrl[0]` contains the url with the prefix and suffix slash '/' on, `linkUrl[1]` is the first url part, `linkUrl[2]` the second

Having brackets in the regex selects what the 'matches' are, so: `link.attr("href").match(/\/([_a-z]+)\/([a-z]+)\//);`

returns `["/_shop/category/", "_shop", "category"]`

Comment: Nice! So the match, can you explain what this is doing - guessing it's making an array of the URL parts?

Comment: Yes that's right, have added a short explanation to the answer